# PHP Ajax add to cart not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi my add to cart button is not working with ajax and i cant see where the problem is. So far when I clicked the add to cart button nothing is happening like the button is not calling the ajax function. Can you guys help me with this I'm new to ajax and I resources on internet can't help me either on this. Thanks

## Button

```
<input type="button" name="add_to_cart" id = "<?PHP echo $row["cardID"];?>" class="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />
```

## Ajax

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(data){

  $('.add_to_cart').click(function(){
    var product_id = $(this).attr("cardID");
    var prodcut_name = $('#name' + product_id).val();
    var product_price = $('#price' + product_id).val();
    var product_quantity = $('#quantity' + product_id).val();
    var action = "add";
     if(product_quantity > 0){
       $.ajax({
       url="action.php",
       method:"POST",
       dataType:"json",
       data:{
          product_id:product_id,
          prodcut_name:prodcut_name,
          product_price:product_price,
          product_quantity:product_quantity,
          action:action
        },
        success:function(data)
        {
         $('#order_table').html(data.order_table);
         $('.badge').text(data.cart_item);
      alert("Product has been added to cart");
        }
    });
  }else{
    alert("Please Enter Number of Quantity");
  }
  });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my action.php

## action.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST["product_id"]))
{
$order_table = '';
$message = '';
if($_POST["action"] == "add")
{
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $is_available = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == 
$_POST["product_id"])
            {
                $is_available++;
                $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] = 
$_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_quantity'] + $_POST["product_quantity"];
            }
        }
        if($is_available < 1)
        {
            $item_array = array(
                'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
                'product_quantity'      =>  $_POST["product_quantity"],
                'product_name'          =>  $_POST["product_name"],
                'product_price'         =>  $_POST["[product_price"]
            );
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $item_array = array (
                'product_id'            =>  $_POST["product_id"],
                'product_quantity'      =>  $_POST["product_quantity"],
                'product_name'          =>  $_POST["product_name"],
                'product_price'         =>  $_POST["[product_price"]
        );
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $item_array;
    }
    $order_table .= '
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th width = "20%">Quantity</th>
            <th width = "40%">Card</th>
            <th width = "20%">Price</th>
            <th width = "20%">Action</th>
        </tr>
    ';
    if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $total = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
        {
            $order_table .= '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$values["product_quantity"].'</td>
                    <td>'.$values["product_name"].'</td>
                    <td align = "right">'.$values["product_price"].'</td>
                    <td><button name = "delete" class = "delete" id="'.$values["product_id"].'">&times;</button></td>
                </tr>
            ';
            $total = $total + ($values["product_quantity"] * $values["product_price"]);
        }
        $order_table .='
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align = "right">Total</td>
                <td align = "right">$ '.number_format($total, 2).'</td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    $order_table .= '</table>';
        $output = array(
            'order_table'       =>  $order_table,
            'cart_item'         =>  count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($output);

}
?>
```

Thanks in advance guys new in ajax.

Comment: are you able to `console.log` on `$('.add_to_cart').click`?

Comment: This sounds like a great opportunity to begin to familiarize yourself with debugging.  Take a look at the development tools in your web browser.  There's a console which would display any JavaScript errors or in which you can test JavaScript code.  There's a network tab to show you HTTP requests and responses (for example, an AJAX call and the server's response).  There's a debugger where you can place breakpoints in your code and step through it line by line as it executes.  Use these tools to examine the problem and narrow down where it's failing.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer`

Comment: @jared: `url="action.php"` is a typo, should be: `url:"action.php"`.  Just like the rest of the object property initializers throughout the code.

Comment: @Eddie - I tried putting `console.log("qweascxz");` inside the `.click` and as @David said i found out about inspect element and finding it on console but nothing is showing inside console tab.

Comment: @David - Thanks so much man. That helped me alot. And now its working.

Comment: @David - Why this ajax don't automatically put items on my cart? Is there a problem in my ajax?

Comment: @Eddie- Why this ajax don't automatically put items on my cart? Is there a problem in my ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to with this line

```
var product_id = $(this).attr("cardID");
```

There is no such attribute. It seems you want to get the id of the element.Replace it with `id`

```
var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: Why this ajax don't automatically put items on my cart? Is there a problem in my ajax?