# ajax add to cart using php and sessions

Tags: php, ajax

Similarly as in [PHP Ajax add to cart not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482086/php-ajax-add-to-cart-not-working) my add to cart is also not working. I am trying to show the added product name, price, quantity and total price in                                        `<div id="mycart"> here </div>` but it's not working and I am not getting any errors in console. Things that do work:

- I get the success alert: Product has been added to cart
  but it doesn't show up in my div.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My form on products.php

```
<form class="form-item" method="post" action="?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"> 
bla bla input
<input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" value="Add to cart">
```

My ajax.js

```
<script>
$('.form-item').on('submit', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var titel = $('#titel' + id).val();
    var price = $('#price' + id).val();
    var quantity = $('#quantity' + id).val();

$.ajax({
           url:"cart-process.php",
           method:"POST",
           dataType:"json",
           data:{
              id:id,
              titel:titel,
              price:price,
              quantity:quantity,
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
             $('#mycart').html(data);
             alert("Product has been added to cart");
            }
        });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

and my cart-process.php

```
<?php   
session_start();

if(!empty($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){  
    $total = 0;  

    foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $row){ 

    $output .='<a href="?action=delete&id='.$row['id'].'" class="action-icon close-shopping-cart-box"><i class="ti ti-close"></i></a>';
    $output .='<span>'.$row['titel'].'</span><span class="text-muted"> x '.$row['quantity'].'</span><br /> ';


    $total = $total + ($row['quantity'] * $row['prijs']);  
    }  

    $output.='<br />Totaal:&euro; '.number_format($total, 2).'';



if (isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'])){
if (count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) > 0){

    $output.='<a href="checkout-cash" style="margin-top:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Cash payment</a>';
    $output.='<a href="checkout-paypal" style="margin-top:20px;" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Paypal payment</a>';

 }}
```

}

```
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: You don't `echo` or `return` anything in your PHP script. You expect `json` from your Ajax, but your PHP does nothing special to encode to JSON format. I don't understand your code.

Comment: See my edited version. I echo the $output now and encode the output to JSON. Now I get the alert message "Product has been added to cart" But I can't see where ...

Comment: Check what `data` is in console just above the line where you try to add it to the dom: `console.log(data); $('#mycart').html(data);`. What do you get?

Comment: Also, use `{` and `}` for blocks instead of `:` and `endforeach` / `endif` to make the code more readable.

Comment: Damnit, I get null when I console log the data. Basically nothing happens. Does this mean the problem is in my cart-process file rather the ajax script? Thanks, will use the curly brackets!

Comment: It is not only the curly brackets. Your ajax call expects JSON is returned (because you have this: `dataType:"json",`), but that is not what your PHP is trying to return. In PHP you are building up the `$output` to be HTML but then you `json_encode` it (which is why you get null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see it may be 3 problems

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
       url:"cart-process.php",   // script location
       method:"POST",            // if you use post, then get the values from $_POST
       //dataType:"json", NO NEED
       data:{
          id:id,                 // this is how the array will be read
          titel:titel,
          price:price,
          quantity:quantity,
        },
        success:function(data)          //success call
        {
         $('#mycart').html(data);        
         alert("Product has been added to cart");  // even if no data is returned 
                                                   //alert will be shown
        }
    });
return false;
```

**Your are posting with an ajax/js script**

Must obtain the variables from the `$_POST array` on server side, but on the server side i dont see when you are adding new product to your chart.

**If you are saving the new product to the session**

```
//as the var names on your js script will be preserved on php side
// you can just add it, if you dont needd to process this info
$_SESSION["shoping_cart"][] = $_POST;
//Now you use a loop to build the html
```

And here is where the **third problem** shows, your ajax call expects a JSON response and, php `json_encoding` the html response? no need, just `echo $html;` and on your js `data = $html` after the succesfull call, then add the html to the element,

`$("#elementid .orclass").html(data)`

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Yes! This almost works! It was really that I thought I had already added the $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][] = $_POST;

The only issue is that the array is not read correctly. Hence, the data is not shown properly (no name, price or quantity of product). I need to fix this in the JS.
Thanks, also to @majid-fouladpour

Comment: before commiting to create the `html` keep your ajax call and add the data to the html element. Try this on the php script `foreach($_SESSION['shopping_data'] as $v){ echo implode(',',$v);}` this will just echo all the values recieved then when all is "Correct" just loop the array formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes, first, tell your ajax function that you expect to receive html response:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"cart-process.php",
  method:"POST",
  dataType:"html",
  ...
```

Second, do not try to json encode the PHP output, it is *not* json:

```
echo $output; // not json_encode($output);
```

Comment: First I tried html as the dataType, but that just returned blank in the console log. So that is why I tried the json method. Both won't work. I don't see what else I can try, so I will redesign the entire php code, maybe the problem is there.

Comment: You need to be consistent. You can switch to using JSON but when you *expect* json (`dataType:"json"`), you also need to generate json in PHP *AND* use the returned json to *build* html to add to the page.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did. With dataType json and json_encode, I get null in console log. With dataType html without json_encode, I get a blank console log.